# Which statistical test should I use for my research?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures

I have taken body temperatures of 5 hens in March 2022 and body temperatures of the same hens in July 2022.  I have also measured egg production, feed intake, and body weight for both months.  I am trying to show that high environmental temperatures alter the hen's physiology, behavior, and egg production.  Please help.  I don't know what test or tests to run for my research.

Comment: Are the measurements taken every day in the months of March 2022 and July 2022, or a specific date? Or haphazardly throughout each of those months? Or according to a systemic data collection procedure?

Comment: to strengthen Galen's comments, please add more details about how the data have been collected.

Comment: All measurements were taken each day of March and each day of July.

Comment: Data was collected in March to use as a baseline for the temperatures in July to show that the birds are exhibiting the signs of heat stress.